# How to create a simple/empty Java Library project to compile as an Android Service for Unity?

Tags: java, windows, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-service

Coming from someone who's only worked in Java casually / when situations absolutely called for it - I'm having a hard time trying to set this up.

I'm trying to follow along this tutorial to build a native Android plugin usable from Unity:
http://jeanmeyblum.weebly.com/scripts--tutorials/communication-between-an-android-app-and-unity

But unfortunately the author skips over the basic steps (understandable for those with prior android dev experience... but not for me!)

I've gone through a checklist of what I had to install, and so far I have:

- Android SDK / Android Studio.
- Java SDK / SRE 1.8.
- Apache ANT.
- Made sure I added all the paths required in my PATH System Environment variable to execute:

  - `android`
  - `ant`
  - and... `java`

But at this point, I have no idea what type of Android project I'm supposed to create (see image).

[image]

Other puzzling questions: Which SDK do I choose, do I just leave that to default? How do I indicate that this is only a Service JAR, and not an Activity? (assuming that's what's required to be usable in Unity3D).

And after the project is created, can I just open one of the existing classes to write my Service inside it? Or do I need to create a new class file and extend from Service / IntentService?

I can probably figure out the rest to implement in Unity3D after I can manage to compile the JAR file. It's just that initial step I have no idea how to setup.

Answer (score 2):

You will choose very first one "Add No Activity"

The tutorial you are following might be outdated. Here is a good one : http://eppz.eu/blog/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-1/